# Joining table of different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I am looking to join a table twice on different conditions. Please read the example below even if the above lines doesn't make sense. I tried left joining the same table using CASE WHEN, but I am not getting the desired output, and I am new to SQL.

There is a table called `MeterReading` which has meter reading values for a specific month. I want to create a join table that has the meter reading for the current month, and also the meter reading value of the previous month.

The month and year are integer values. Everything in the example are integer values.

Table MeterReading

| MeterID | YearVal | MonthVal | ReadingVal | UsingVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 | 120 | 140 |
| 3 | 2020 | 3 | 180 | 200 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | 2020 | 12 | 140 | 200 |
| 13 | 2021 | 1 | 230 | 170 |
| 14 | 2021 | 2 | 120 | 100 |

The output I am looking for is like:

| MeterID | YearVal | MonthVal | ReadingVal | UsingVal | PrevVal | PrevUsingVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 | 100 | 150 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 | 120 | 140 | 100 | 150 |
| 3 | 2020 | 3 | 180 | 200 | 120 | 140 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | 2020 | 12 | 140 | 200 | ... | ... |
| 13 | 2021 | 1 | 230 | 170 | 140 | 200 |
| 14 | 2021 | 2 | 120 | 100 | 230 | 170 |

Also to be noted that since year and month are integers, the previous of 2021 01 will be 2020 12.

The query I tried is (again, I am very new to SQL):

```
SELECT
MR.meterid ,
MR.year_val,
MR.month_val,
MR.reading_val,
MR.using_val,
TMR.Meterid,
TMR.YV2,
TMR.MV2,
TMR.RV1,
TMR.UV2,
0 AS DelFlag
From MeterReading MR
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
    MR.meterid,
    MR.Reading_val AS RV1 ,
    MR.using_val AS UV2,
    CASE WHEN MR.Month_val = 1 THEN 12 ELSE MR.Month_val - 1  END AS MV2,
    CASE WHEN MR.month_val = 1 THEN MR.year_val + 1 ELSE MR.year_val END AS YV2
    FROM MeterReading MR
) TMR
ON
MR.meterid = TMR.meterid AND
MR.year_val = TMR.YV2 AND
MR.month_val = TMR.MV2
```

I am not getting the expected result. Please guide me with a simple explanation.

Comment: Look into `lag` window function.

Comment: Thanks Stu. That was helpful.. But What if there are irregular entries... Is there a way for it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in a very beginner way, by LEFT JOIN-ing the same table on conditions with [ CASE WHEN ] for  boundary cases of month and year (ie previous val of 2020 January should fetch value of December 2019),

QUERY:

```
SELECT
  TMR.MeterID
, TMR.YearVal
, TMR.MonthVal
, TMR.ReadingVal AS ReadingVal
, TMR.UsingVal AS UsingVal
, TMR2.ReadingVal AS PrevReadVal
, TMR2.Using AS PrevUsingVal
FROM MeterReading TMR
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    TMR.MeterID
  , TMR.ReadingVal
  , TMR.UsingVal
  , CASE WHEN TMR.MonthVal = '12' THEN 1 ELSE TMR.MonthVal + 1 END AS MonthVal2
  , CASE WHEN TMR.MonthVal = '12' THEN TMR.YearVal + 1 ELSE TMR.YearVal END AS YearVal2
  FROM MeterReading TMR
) TMR2 ON
TMR.MeterID = TMR2.MeterID
AND TMR.YearVal = TMR2.YearVal2
AND TMR.MonthVal = TMR2.MonthVal2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have data for every month, you can use a simple lag:

```
select mr.*,
       lag(readingval) over (order by yearval, monthval) as prev_readingval,
       lag(usingval) over (order by yearval, monthval) as prev_usingval
from MeterReading mr;
```

If you could be missing data and you want to treat that as `NULL` (rather than going to the previous month in the data), you can still use window functions but using the `range` window frame:

```
select mr.*,
       sum(readingval) over (order by yearval * 12 + monthval
                             range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                            ) as prev_readingval,
       lag(usingval) over (order by yearval * 12 + monthval
                           range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                          ) as prev_usingval
from MeterReading mr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LAG()` should do it for simple cases. However, if you want more flexibility, using a `JOIN` should be preferred. You can try the one below :

```
SELECT          currentYear.MeterID, currentYear.YearVal, currentYear.MonthVal, currentYear.ReadingVal, currentYear.UsingVal, previousYear.ReadingVal AS PrevVal, previousYear.UsingVal AS PrevUsingVal
FROM            #MeterReading currentYear
LEFT JOIN       #MeterReading previousYear ON (currentYear.YearVal = previousYear.YearVal AND (currentYear.MonthVal - 1) = previousYear.MonthVal)
WHERE           currentYear.MonthVal != 1
UNION
SELECT          currentYear.MeterID, currentYear.YearVal, currentYear.MonthVal, currentYear.ReadingVal, currentYear.UsingVal, previousYear.ReadingVal AS PrevVal, previousYear.UsingVal AS PrevUsingVal
FROM            #MeterReading currentYear
LEFT JOIN       #MeterReading previousYear ON ((currentYear.YearVal - 1) = previousYear.YearVal) AND (previousYear.MonthVal = 12)
WHERE           currentYear.MonthVal = 1

ORDER BY        currentYear.YearVal ASC, currentYear.MonthVal ASC
```